# In this syntax for setting OnItemClick for Android ListView. What is the difference between id and position?

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter, onclicklistener

In this syntax for setting `OnItemClick` for android `ListView`. What is the difference between id and position?

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, final View view, int position, long id)
```

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html

Answer (score 0):

In the above syntax, position means on which item position you have clicked and Id means the id of the view you clicked

Comment: Are they both not the same.. like id 0 is placed in position 0 .Correct me if I am telling wrong.

Comment: They are not both the same. It is like id 1 is placed in 2nd/3rd/4th position

Answer (score 0):

position-->The position of the view in the adapter.

id-->The row id of the item that was clicked.

[AdapterView.OnItemClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.html)